# Strange Behaviour of array_push() in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am facing a strange problem in array_push function of php.

Lets see my code:

```
$sets_collection=array();
foreach($result['ques'] as $val){
      $sets_collection=array_push($sets_collection,$val['set']);
      }
```

than it gives me the error:
Message: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given

But when i do this ,it works fine:

```
$sets_collection=array();
      $i=0;
        foreach($result['ques'] as $val)
        {
        $sets_collection[$i]=$val['set']; 
        $i++;
        }
```

**My question is why this happen,is it necessary that there should be a index of an array than we can perform the push operation?? because in my 1st case the array $set_collection has not an any index and please let me know why this happened??**

Comment: RTFM for [`array_push`](http://php.net/array_push), see its *return value* and read the examples.

Comment: syntax error ! `$sets_collection[]=$val['set']` is same as `array_push($sets_collection,$val['set'])` ,and array_push returns new array count. After 1st iteration you will see the error in case 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$sets_collection=array();

foreach($result['ques'] as $val){
    array_push($sets_collection,$val['set']); 
}
```

Comment: i tried same in my 1st case ,this gave me error.

Comment: No i got now my mistake,this works fine...Thanks:(

Answer (score 2):

That's because [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) returns the new number of elements inside the array. You don't assign the returned value to the array variable. The first parameter is actually passed by reference. Thus, its value is mutated by the function.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `array_push` returns new number of elements in the array, when you pushes the array in first iteration it works but in second iteration `$sets_collection becomes 1` which is an `integer` so the function fails with the mentioned error.

Reference: [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0):

`array_push` does not return an array - just an integer. Perhaps as the variable `sets_collection` is presumed to have changed to an integer because of the expected return of `array_push`, the subsequent parameter is also treated as an integer.

Just remove the assignment, and it should work fine.

```
array_push($sets_collection,$val['set']);
```